# How to make the request with valid URL string without encoding characters?

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, url-encoding

I am making a simple get request for URL:-

```
http://localhost:9061/demo/v2/outcome?class=ABC&params=(Id=1bf854a3-3146-4a94-a444-1a609fe1893a,ver=1,required=true)
```

I am using webclient to make get request like:-

```
    FluxExchangeResult<String> result = webTestClient.get().uri(URL)
    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).header("Authorization", 
    "r0u+.vj6/+2HK.\\uB76F\\u299C")
    .exchange().expectStatus().isOk().returnResult(String.class);
```

where URL is the above mentioned URL.
When i make this request i am getting 404 as my URL is encoded in the form

```
http://localhost:9061/demo/v2/outcome?class=ABC&params=(Id%3D1bf854a3-3146-4a94-a444-1a609fe1893a,ver%3D1,required%3Dtrue)
```

Why is the '=' inside the braces is encoded only and how can i correct this?

Comment: `=` is part  of the parameter scheme ie `{url}?param1=value1&param2=value2` so urlencoding it will of course encode the equals signs...

Comment: Why is it then only encoding the = within braces one?

Comment: Because the rest of the equals signs are part of the `parameter,value` pairs I mentioned earlier. so `param1=abc=` would be encoded as `param1=abc%3D` since there is already one equals sign denoting the parameter. any other equals sign encountered before a `&` will be encoded. So if you wrote `param1=abc=&param2=def` it would be `param1=abc%3D&param2=def`  etc

Comment: So how can i make this get request correctly?